# How to smoothly handle a json array with 200k rows using volly

Tags: android, json, android-volley, large-files

I have [url](http://43.255.22.123:3000/android/mis/get/ipdAdmitPatMd) that has a json Array which contains a large amount of data. 
I call the url with volly jsonArrayRequest like this

```
public void makeJsonArrayReq(){
    showProgressDialog();
    JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(Const.URL_IPD_ADMITED,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d("response ================", response.toString());
                    textView.setText(response.toString());
                    hideProgressDialog();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d("Error", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            textView.setText("Error Occurs ");
            hideProgressDialog();
        }
    });
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req, "array");
```

}

My devise shows progressDialog for some time after that time it hang out the app then after a few minute  it shows the response in the texview but it very lengthy  process and it same when internet connection off and extract from  volley cache. How can I handle the URL in my apps?

Comment: use pagination for it

Comment: actually i am a new android developer how to use pagination in android

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your api a bit to support pagination. There are several pagination techniques available, you have to choose one that suites your case.

In `Android` you can save the last fetched `pageNumber`(if that is what your API returns as page identifier) and your api should accept this variable in request (mostly through query params)

```
http://43.255.22.123:3000/android/mis/get/ipdAdmitPatMd?pageId=1
```

And in the next request it should update the pageId to 2.

Since the question is too broad hence providing exact code solution is not possible therefore I have explained the concept.